# WPF: Dialog vanishes when launched in separate UI thread

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, multithreading

I have been working on a scenario where we have to launch a dialog in a separate thread with STA Apartment state. Child parent relationship is being established like this (which is successful).

```
WindowInteropHelper interOPHelper = new WindowInteropHelper (window);
//parentWindow is handle of the parent
interOPHelper.Owner = parentWindow;
```

When the dialog launches it comes on top of the parent window and everything works fine, both of the dialogs (parent and child) are there in taskbar. But when ‘Windows + D’ (shortcut key) or ‘Windows + M’ is pressed, the child dialog vanishes from task bar. Clicking on parent dialog in taskbar does not restore the dialog. Even pressing Alt + Tab to restore the parent dialog did not work. Eventually application has to be killed from TaskManager.

```
private void ShowDialog(IntPtr parentWindow) {

        Thread staThread = new Thread (() =>
        {
            ChildWindow window = new ChildWindow ();
            window.Closed += (s, e2) => Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvokeShutdown (DispatcherPriority.Background);

            WindowInteropHelper interOPHelper = new WindowInteropHelper (window);
            //parentWindow is handle of the parent
            interOPHelper.Owner = parentWindow;
            window.ShowDialog ();
            GC.Collect ();
        });
        staThread.Name = "STAThread";
        staThread.SetApartmentState (ApartmentState.STA);
        staThread.Start ();
        staThread.Join ();
        }
}
```

NOTE: This behavior does not appear if I do NOT set the owner of window object (but that is not deemed behavior of-course).

Comment: Why are you creating a Window in a separate thread? Maybe it is best to fix the reason for that rather than trying to fix this problem...

Comment: Glen! I fear now refactor might not be an option (let me try explaining). We have desktop services responsible for fetching data from cloud (this dialog resides in this service). Hundreds of our applications written in (Win32, MFC, WinForms, WPF) make a call in this service and this dialog pops up, we establish child-parent relationship of this dialog and calling application main window. Based upon user input the data is returned back to the calling applications. Concurrent invocation into this service would not be uncommon. Hope this would help you understand why we have this kind of design.